# Assemble/handlebars: run custom function defined in external js file

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

given I have this javascript file

**src/js/functions.js**

```
(function() { 

    crc32 = function(str, crc ) { 
    ...
    }; 
})();
```

This file is part of the static website, **and** I want to use crc32() in a template, like this:

**index.hbs**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var crc_checksum = {{checksum solution}};
</script>
```

Of course that needs an intermediate helper

**helpers.js**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('checksum', function(value){
    this.checksum = return value;
});
```

I don't want to copy-paste the crc32 code into the helper (as this would duplicate the code). Is there any way of loading an external JS-file into the namespace of the helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build your `crc32` file in the "node.js" way and use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to use it in your site. There are also other ways to make your `crc32` object available on both node and the browser. Then you can `require` it in your helper file...

**src/js/functions.js**

```
(function(exports) {
  exports.crc32 = function (str, crc) { ... };
})(window || module.exports);
```

**helpers.js**

```
var crc32 = require('./src/js/functions').crc32;
Handlebars.registerHelper('checksum', function (value) {
  return crc32(value);
});
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Instead of using browserify (would have been yet another dependency) I used [this method of](http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/writing_for_node_and_the_browser/) of sharing code between node and the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, when creating a helper just follow the same module pattern you would with any other node library.

Wrap the helper in a `module.exports.register` function:

```
module.exports.register = function (Handlebars, options, params) {
  Handlebars.registerHelper('checksum', function(src) {
    return require('your-checksum-lib')(src);
  });
};
```

And then make sure to tell Assemble where the file is:

```
assemble: {
  options: {
    helpers: ['path/to/checksum.js']
  }
}
```

Or... if the helper is actually a npm module itself, you can add it to the `devDependencies` and `keywords` in package.json and Assemble will automatically pick it up. e.g:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "devDependencies": {
    "handlebars-helper-checksum": "~0.1.0",
  },
  "keywords": [
    "handlebars-helper-checksum"
  ]
}
```

However, you could also just make a request or pr for this helper on the [handlebars-helpers](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers) repo, and we could add it to the library.

Comment: thanks Jon. As the module is not an npm module, I ended up using require with the relative path to the js file and added some code to make it available for both browser and node.js. Is there any benefit in telling assemble via `options.helpers` where the file is opposed to require it with the relative path?

Comment: @PhilippKeller if you have multiple helper files in a folder like `./src/helpers/` you could tell assemble via `options.helpers` to load them all. In those helpers you can do `require` for your other modules...
`assemble: { options: { helpers: ['./src/helpers/**/*.js'] } }`

Comment: yes, as @doowb points out, you can use minimatch/glob patterns to load all of your helpers at once. Here is an example project that demonstrates what we're describing: https://github.com/assemble/buttons/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L40